# How do I run the react-script start with chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I need your help!!
I create react app on my pc
I use npm start to run it on live server but its browser is'nt chrome.How can I run it as chrome browser?
I have checked setting but I cant see place to fix.
I 'm new beginer so hope guys please teach me!

Comment: set chrome as your default browser. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Answer (score -1):

Just set Chrome as your default browser,
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop